# unable to enable a chrome extension installed from CRX

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a CRX file of my extension (the CRX is version 3 format)
I was able to install the extension on my MacOS by drag and dropping it into Google Chrome's Extensions view.
But other people who use Windows 10, have issue which prevents them from enabling the Extension after they install it.
They see a red warning text: "*This extension is not listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge.*"
And they are unable to enable the Extension - the slider is grayed out and unclickable.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ5ad.png)
What can be done to make this work?
I know I can use chrome store instead of installing from CRX. but I need this as a workaround for my users who need the latest version immediately. Because the reviews by Google when I deploy new version started to take days.

Comment: They'll have to edit group policy as explained in [this answer](/a/38011386) or switch to non-stable Chrome like dev channel or Canary or use a fork of Chromium.